# AngularJS questions change based on previous answers

Tags: angularjs

I am creating an application in which I would like my app to have the below functionality in AngularJS.
Whenever I answer my first question, the next question should change based on my previous selection. I want to use purely Angular to solve this issue.
Could anyone please help me achieve this ?

Related code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/XSNIGn0SkDKy1DgYNWkc?p=preview

I have added all the required files, though the plunker won't work

Directive:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var questionDir = function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
              config: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {

            },
            templateUrl: 'question.html'
        };
    }

    angular.module('questionnaire.directive')
        .directive('question', questionDir);
}());
```

Comment: I couldn't make the Plunker work but all my files work on a local machine. I have tried to add some validations so that the answers are selected before submitting, and also I tried to write some functions to achieve the logic for questions to change based on the previous answers selected.

Comment: I would need some logic which lets the questions change based on the previous answers selected, for example if I select the age in first question, second question should change based on the answer. Like the second question can be: What do you drive ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bz9yhSoPYUNzFDpfASwt?p=preview
This plunker is somewhat close to my requirement.